# Deleting the first element of the N-D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy 5D array and want to delete the first element and push a new element to the end of the index. Here goes the definition;

```
images = np.zeros([1,30,image_height,image_width,image_channel])
```

This is the one to be deleted: `images[0,0,:,:,:]`

And this is the one to be updated: `images[0,29,:,:,:]`

How to delete and add an element from N-D sized array?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it out.

```
images[0, 0:28, :, :, :] = images[0, 1:29, :, :, :]

images[0, 30, :, :, :] = new_data
```

---

To avoid *hardcoding* indices it can be written as:

```
images[0,0:-1,...] = images[0,1:,...]
images[0,-1,...] = new_data
```

Comment: `images[0, 29, :, :, :] = new_data`?

Comment: Hum..originally I wish to push the new data at the end of array every iteration and delete the oldest one. new_data is a symbolic value that will replace the last element. And new_data will be a color image.

Comment: Indices are zero based, if the shape of the array is (1, 30, x, y, z) as indicated in your question, then the largest index for the second dimension should by 29.

Comment: [numpy.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html#numpy.roll) could be used to roll the values *forward*, then replace the last one. It may be less efficient though as it creates a new array.